# Unable to install Xgbhoost package in R on windows 8.1

Tags: r, package

When I tried to install the `xgboost` package I've got the following error

```
install.packages("xgboost")
```

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/praveen/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>
> Warning in install.packages :   package
>   ‘xgboost’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)

Comment: I'm sorry. there is a small typo in my post..I just edited it..

Comment: You need to update to the current R version, R 3.2.1.  Else you need to build from source.

Comment: How can I update to current version ?

Comment: Go to https://www.r-project.org/ and follow the instructions

Comment: Just how you installed version 3.1.2.  See the R FAQ for more.

Comment: I have updated to current version..but still getting the same error   :--                         
_package ‘xgboost’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to following code. I am using RRO 3.2.1 in Windows 7 with Rstudio 0.99.441
Copied from this [link on kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/nigelcarpenter/liberty-mutual-group-property-inspection-prediction/r-xgboost-with-gini-eval-and-stopping/discussion/comment/85583)

```
  install.packages("RCurl")
  install.packages("Rcpp")
  install.packages("xml2")
  install.packages("devtools")
  devtools::install_github('dmlc/xgboost',subdir='R-package')

  # load packages
  library(xgboost)
```

The older Rtools.exe doesn't work in the updated R version. Re-installing all the above did the trixk!